# Getting an error when using replace in for loop, NoneType object has no attribute replace?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python: 3.4

So for some reason the following code throws an error in python console.

But the `append` is working and I get the correct(`replace` process completed) values in the new list.

```
mobile = []
for col in ws.iter_cols():
    for cell in col:
        if cell.value == 'Mobile':
            x=column_index_from_string(cell.column)
            for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col = x, min_row = 2, max_col = x):
                for cell in row:
                    mobile.append(cell.value)
mob_f = []
for i in mobile:
    h = i
    h = h.replace(" ","")
    h = h.replace("+(91)-",",")
    h = h.replace("+91","")
    h = h.replace("-","")
    mob_f.append(h)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 3, in 
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Whatever `ws` is (apparently some 2-dim data structure), some of its cells' `value` is `None`. And `None` has no method `replace`!

Comment: Oh..Ok. Got it. Need to add some code to handle that before generating the list. Thanks.